`ign gazebo` and `gz sim` commands not working
I am struggling to run Ignition Gazebo. I am running ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I was trying to get this example (https://github.com/art-e-fact/navigation2_ignition_gazebo_example) to work but I was facing the errors shown below.
I cannot find any available 'ign' command:
    * Did you install any ignition library?
    * Did you set the IGN_CONFIG_PATH environment variable?
        E.g.: export IGN_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/local/share/ignition

I even checked my ~/.bashrc file, which shows the line export IGN_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/local/share/ignition. Where am I supposed to find the ign gazebo command stored after installation via Binary Install from the Ignition Gazebo documentation?
Likewise, when I try to run gz sim, the following menu of options shows up:
This tool modifies various aspects of a running Gazebo simulation.

  Usage:  gz <command>

List of commands:

  help      Print this help text.
  camera    Control a camera
  debug     Returns completion list for a command. Used for bash completion.
  help      Outputs information about a command
  joint     Modify properties of a joint
  log       Introspects and manipulates Gazebo log files.
  marker    Add, modify, or delete visual markers
  model     Modify properties of a model
  physics   Modify properties of the physics engine
  sdf       Converts between SDF versions, and provides info about SDF files
  stats     Print statistics about a running gzserver instance.
  topic     Lists information about topics on a Gazebo master
  world     Modify world properties


Use "gz help <command>" to print help for a command.
The above result shows up even when I run gz sim with a .sdf file.

What are the proper installation steps and am I missing anything?
